# How do you split rows within the same table into columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a very simple table like this:

[image]

And I want a a query to return that data in 1 row, like this:

[image]

How do I go about doing that?  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT
    od.OrderNo,
    CASE
        WHEN od.PartNo LIKE 'CAD%' THEN od.PartNo
        END AS [Part1],
    CASE
        WHEN od.PartNo LIKE 'CAD%' THEN od.DueDate
        END AS [DueDate1],
    CASE
        WHEN od.PartNo LIKE 'WISH%' THEN od.PartNo
        END AS [Part2],
    CASE
        WHEN od.PartNo LIKE 'WISH%' THEN od.DueDate
        END AS [DueDate2]
FROM OrderDet od
WHERE od.OrderNo = '20352E'
    AND (od.PartNo LIKE 'CAD%'
    OR od.PartNo LIKE 'WISH%')
```

The result I'm getting from this is as follows:

[image]

I also tried a self join, like this:

```
SELECT
    od.OrderNo,
    od.PartNo AS [Part1],
    od.DueDate AS [DueDate1],
    od2.PartNo AS [Part2],
    od2.DueDate AS [DueDate2]
FROM OrderDet od
    JOIN OrderDet od2 ON od.OrderNo = od2.OrderNo
WHERE od.OrderNo = '20352E'
    AND (od.PartNo LIKE 'CAD%'
    OR od2.PartNo LIKE 'WISH%')
```

That didn't work either, however, row 8 is the one I want, just not sure how to isolate is, the result is as follows:

[image]

So is there a way to actually do what I want and have it show in 1 row?  Can't wrap my head around it.  Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: In your join you compare part numbers but the part numbers are not the same in the table you show at the top

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that.  I removed that and I got a larger table, however, 1 of those rows is the row I want, hmmm.  Going to edit my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` clause and do *conditional* aggregation

```
select OrderNo,
       max(case when PartNo LIKE 'CAD%' then 'CAD' end) as PartNo1,
       max(case when PartNo LIKE 'CAD%' then DueDate end) as DueDate1,
       max(case when PartNo LIKE 'WISH%' then 'WISH' end) as PartNo2,
       max(case when PartNo LIKE 'WISH%' then DueDate end) as DueDate2
from OrderDet o
where OrderNo = '20352E' and 
      (PartNo LIKE 'CAD%' or PartNo LIKE 'WISH%')
group by OrderNo;
```

Comment: It returns a blank table

Comment: @user1452574... i misread the question use `LIKE` predicate instead.

Comment: Your answer is the best one, thanks.  Works great even when there are nulls

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    OrderNo,
    (SELECT  MAX(PartNo) FROM OrderDet) AS [Part1],
    (SELECT  MAX(DueDate) FROM OrderDet) AS [DueDate1],
    (SELECT  MIN(PartNo) FROM OrderDet) AS [Part2],
    (SELECT  MIN(DueDate) FROM OrderDet) AS [DueDate2]
FROM OrderDet
WHERE od.OrderNo = '20352E'
    AND (od.PartNo LIKE 'CAD%'
    OR od2.PartNo LIKE 'WISH%')
GROUP BY OrderNo
```